# js Office addin trying to get text input field to pass a variable to the graph API call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I started with this project
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs

I modified it to add an input box and tried changing the API call to include the input field as search field.  I wanted to pull that input by its ID in the app.js file but I can't seem to pull the value.

SearchTxt and SearchBtn both show in Visual Studio grayed out with variable is declared but it’s value is never read. Any assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

I included the full pug file below and the relevant part of app.js

index.pug

```
  div.ms-fontSize-xl.ms-fontColor-themePrimary Welcome
  div.ms-fontSize-xl.ms-fontColor-themePrimary Search
  searchvalue: <input type="text" name="Search" value="" id="SPsearch" placeholder="Type something..." style="text-align:center;"/>
  <button type="button" onclick=getInputValue();>Get Value</button>
script.
  let SPsearch = #{newId}
  localStorage.setItem('SPsearch', SPsearch)




      div.ms-font-l This add-in demonstrates how to connect to Microsoft Graph from an add-in.
    div.welcome-body
      p.ms-font-xs.welcome-intro This add-in performs the following tasks:
      ul#file-list.ms-List.ordered-list
        li.ms-listItem #[span.ms-ListItem-primaryText 1] #[span.ms-ListItem-secondaryText Connects to SharePoint]
        li.ms-listItem #[span.ms-ListItem-primaryText 2] #[span.ms-ListItem-secondaryText Gets the names of the first ten files and folders in OneDrive.]
        li.ms-listItem #[span.ms-ListItem-primaryText 3] #[span.ms-ListItem-secondaryText Adds the names to the current document.]
       
    div#message-area.welcome.ms-font-l

  footer#footer.homefooter.ms-bgColor-neutralLight
    div.container
      p(style="text-align:center;") 
        button#getGraphDataButton.popupButton.ms-Button.ms-Button--primary
          span.ms-Button-label Get SharePoint File Names
```

app.js

```
 const searchText = document.getElementByID('SPsearch').value;
 document.getElementByID('getGraphDataButton').addEventListener('click',search());
  const SPpathwSearch = "/groups/{????????-????-????-????-????????????}/drive/root/search(q=${searchText})"
```

SSOauth.js
I also tried to pull the variable value with the button click

```
    Office.onReady(function (info) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#getGraphDataButton').click(getGraphData);
        });
    });
```

I also tried setting up a function in the public/javascript folder.

getinputvalue.js

```
var inputVal;
    function getInputValue(){
            // Selecting the input element and get its value
             inputVal.addEventListener('click')
             inputVal = document.getElementById('SPsearch').value;
             console.log(inputValue))
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Sorry that button I was trying to test because I could not figure out how to do it with the existing button at the bottom.

I changed the original from pulling 10 one drive file names to searching SharePoint. It works when I type directly in the graph API call but can’t get a variable to work from input box

I am trying to connect this input box:

```
  searchvalue: <input type="text" name="Search" value="" id="SPsearch" placeholder="Type something..." style="text-align:center;"/>
```

to push to value from the input field to searchText:

```
const SPpathwSearch = "/groups/{????????-????-????-???? ????????????}/drive/root/search(q=${searchText})"
const graphData = await getGraphData(graphToken, SPpathwSearch,"?$select=name,id,webUrl,thumbnails");
```

When this button is pushed:

```
 p(style="text-align:center;") 
        button#getsearchButton.popupButton.ms-Button.ms-Button--primary
          span.ms-Button-label Search SharePoint
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code exactly what you are trying to do. One thing that I notice is that when your code assigns handlers, it has parentheses after the function name. For example

```
<button type="button" onclick=getInputValue();>Get Value</button
```

And

```
addEventListener('click',search());
```

This is almost never what you want to do. The parentheses tell the JS engine to run the function **right now**. But you don't want to run it now. You want it to run when the associated event occurs. Remove the parentheses. Also, provide more of your code. It looks weird in some ways, such as assigning a handler to an uninitialized variable.